# How to access teams calls notification url using proxy + c#

Tags: c#, microsoft-teams

I am adding webhook teams to get call records using below code.

```
   var sub = new Microsoft.Graph.Subscription();
    sub.ChangeType = "created";
    sub.NotificationUrl = _options.WebhookNoticationUrl;
    sub.Resource = "communications/callRecords";
    sub.ExpirationDateTime =     
    DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(Convert.ToInt32(_options.WebhookExpirationTime)); 
    // add hours
    sub.ClientState = _options.ClientState;

    var newSubscription = await graphServiceClient
      .Subscriptions
      .Request()
    
      .AddAsync(sub);
```

But I want access `NotificationUrl` url using webhook. and then register webhook. I haven't seen any option in `graphServiceClient` to register webhook using proxy. how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GraphClientFactory class to create an HttpClient object that can handle proxy settings. Then you can pass the HttpClient object to the constructor of the GraphServiceClient class. This way, you can use the proxy configuration when creating and managing subscriptions. For example, you can use this sample code:

```
// Create an HttpClient with proxy settings
HttpClient httpClient = GraphClientFactory.Create(
GetClientCredentialProvider(), // Your authentication provider
"v1.0", // Your API version
"Global", // Your national cloud
new WebProxy("your_proxy_url") // Your proxy URL
);

// Create a GraphServiceClient with the HttpClient
var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(httpClient);

// Create a subscription with the GraphServiceClient
var sub = new Microsoft.Graph.Subscription();
sub.ChangeType = "created";
sub.NotificationUrl = _options.WebhookNoticationUrl;
sub.Resource = "communications/callRecords";
sub.ExpirationDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(Convert.ToInt32(_options.WebhookExpirationTime));
sub.ClientState = _options.ClientState;

var newSubscription = await graphServiceClient
.Subscriptions
.Request()
.AddAsync(sub);
```